# How to call dropzone processQueue() from separate function?

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js, formvalidation.io

My form includes dropzone.js and is validated with the jQuery plugin formvalidation.io.

Independently the file upload and validation elements work as expected however I need the form validation to run before Dropzone uploads any files.

I am trying to do this by

- configuring configure Dropzone with `autoProcessQueue: false` to prevent files uploading automatically

  - calling Dropzone `processQueue()` manually from the form validation onSuccess callback

All attempts have failed.  It seems, with my limited javascript knowledge, I cannot access Dropzone from within another function?

I am sure the answer is among the comments on the Dropzone Issue *jQuery instancing: Accessing Dropzone object #180* but I don't know how to implement what is discussed here.
https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/180

Code below has comments showing my attempts to call `processQueue()` along with the results of each.

Can anyone tell me how to call `processQueue()` correctly please?

**Dropzone script**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

// Get the template HTML and remove it from the document
var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
previewNode.id = "";
var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#drop-target', { // define specific dropzone target
  url: "/processors/form-upload-files.html", // Set the url
  previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
  autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually enqueued
  previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
  clickable: ".fileinput-button", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.

  autoProcessQueue: false, // when ready to send files call myDropzone.processQueue()
  uploadMultiple: true,

  init: function() {

    // removed for ease of reading as not relevant to the problem

  } 

});
```

**Formvalidation script** - Code below includes comments showing my attempts to call processQueue() along with the results of each

```
$(function() {
  FormValidation.formValidation(
      document.getElementById('fm-contact'), {
        fields: {
          user_name: {
            validators: {
              notEmpty: {
                message: 'What should we call you?'
              }
            }
          } /* other validators removed for ease of reading */
            }
          }

        },
      }
    )

    /* form is valid, trigger dropzone processQueue() */
    .on('core.form.valid', function() {

      // call dropzone to upload files and data

      // figure if files are queued
    // console.log( myDropzone.getQueuedFiles() ) // returns empty array

    /* console log is empty
    var myDropzone = Dropzone.forElement("#drop-target");
    console.log( myDropzone ) 
    myDropzone.processQueue();
    */

    /* does not process queue, no errors
    $('#drop-target')[0].dropzone.processQueue();
    */

    /* Error: Dropzone already attached. - even with Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; outside of jquery ready function 
    var dropzone1 = new Dropzone("#drop-target", { autoProcessQueue: false, uploadMultiple: true});
    dropzone1.processQueue();
    */

    /* TypeError: dropzone is undefined
    var dropzone = $(this).get(0).dropzone;
    dropzone.processQueue();
    */

    /* does not process queue, no errors
    var dzone = document.querySelector("#drop-target").dropzone;
    dzone.processQueue();
    */


    /* does not process queue, no errors
    Dropzone.forElement("#drop-target").processQueue();
    */

    /* does not process queue, no errors
    var myDropzone = Dropzone.forElement("div#drop-target");
    myDropzone.processQueue();
    */


    /* ReferenceError: options is not defined 
    var drop = $("#drop-target").dropzone({ autoProcessQueue: false, uploadMultiple: true}).get(0).dropzone;
    drop.processQueue();
    */

    /* does not process queue, no errors
    $('#drop-target').get(0).dropzone.processQueue();
    */

    });


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved by configuring Dropzone correctly.  `autoQueue: false,` means the queue is empty when calling `processQueue();`.

It should be `autoQueue: true,`.

Should have realised this but had copied the configuration from the example in the Dropzone docs - line 13 in the second Gist at https://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html

Correct form validation callback is

```
.on('core.form.valid', function() {
    var myDropzone = Dropzone.forElement("#drop-target");
});
```

Thanks to Alastair at 63 Digital for pointing out my stupidity.